# Trying to parse a commandline argument into two separate commands in C

Tags: c, linux, command-line

for a project I'm writing, there's a section where I must break a command line argument into two so that I can run them separately using execvp. I'm stuck as to how to do this, so far what I'm trying to do is pass a command like argument like so:

```
$testprogram /bin/ls , /bin/cat
```

and then break it at the comma so that I can pass /bin/ls and /bin/cat into a generic execvp function separately.

I've tried using a for loop for this with an if statement to ignore the comma but it's not working out so well.

Any ideas?

Comment: *I've tried using a for loop for this with an if statement to ignore the comma but it's not working out so well.* ... Welcome, but always... share what code you've got and precisely the point where you got stuck.  "It's not working out so well" without any code supplied is kind of not any different than "please write my code", and doesn't help understand your problem.  It's hard (for me) to really pinpoint what you intend with "break a command line argument into two"; that could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Hint argv[0] argv[1] argv[2] argv[3]

Answer (score 0):

Just give arguments without comma, with blank spaces like

`$testprogram /bin/ls  /bin/cat`

now,

`argv[0]=testprogram`

`argv[1]=/bin/ls`

`argv[2]=/bin/cat`